# Angular 2 Get request error response,

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to send POST request to the API and if response code == 400 get info from response. 
http://joxi.ru/l2ZM0KES0M8ZmJ

```
public contactUsSendPost(params): Observable<{}> {
    return this.contactUsSendPostWithHttpInfo(params)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json());
}

public contactUsSendPostWithHttpInfo(params): Observable<Response> {
    const path = this.basePath + `/contact-us/send`;

    let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
    let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON());
    let formParams = new URLSearchParams();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

    if (params.email !== undefined) {
        formParams.set('email', <any>params.email);
    }
    if (params.fullName !== undefined) {
        formParams.set('fullName', <any>params.fullName);
    }
    if (params.question !== undefined) {
        formParams.set('question', <any>params.question);
    }

    let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        headers: headers,
        body: formParams.toString(),
        search: queryParameters
    });

    return this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
}
```

Then im trying to get response from the service, but cant get response body.

```
this.fqService.contactUsSendPost(formValues).subscribe(
        data => console.log(data ),
        err => console.log(err) <------ 
    );
```

So, how can i get response body in angular 2 from http response with 400 status code ?

Comment: why are you casting <any> when you set the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to catch the error on your observable, see modified code below.

```
    public contactUsSendPost(params): Observable<{}> {
        return this.contactUsSendPostWithHttpInfo(params)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    public contactUsSendPostWithHttpInfo(params): Observable<Response> {
        const path = this.basePath + `/contact-us/send`;

        let queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
        let headers = new Headers(this.defaultHeaders.toJSON());
        let formParams = new URLSearchParams();
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');

        if (params.email !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('email', <any>params.email);
        }
        if (params.fullName !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('fullName', <any>params.fullName);
        }
        if (params.question !== undefined) {
            formParams.set('question', <any>params.question);
        }

        let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            headers: headers,
            body: formParams.toString(),
            search: queryParameters
        });

        return this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        return Observable.throw(error.code);
    }
```

Comment: Can i get response info (http://joxi.ru/l2ZM0KES0M8ZmJ) from that error object? Or only error code and status?

Comment: I believe it passes the entire error as an object. So you can get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to HttpClient module angular 4.3 and above application,

If you pass the entire request object as a input the http.request method you will get an complete response object.